# Flink - Expose new custom REST API

Tags: apache-flink

In Apache Flink REST API documentation, [in Developing section](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/rest_api/#developing), is written:

> To add new requests, one needs to
>
> - add a new `MessageHeaders` class which serves as an interface for the new request,
> - add a new `AbstractRestHandler` class which handles the request according to the added `MessageHeaders` class,
> - add the handler to `org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorEndpoint#initializeHandlers()`.

I'm able to complete the first two points, but I have no idea about to approach the latter.

This is how my main class looks:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.
        getExecutionEnvironment();
    Source<String> source = ...;
    Sink<String> sink = ...;

    MyJob job = new MyJob(env, source, sink);
    env.execute();
}
```

I see that constructor of `WebMonitorEndpoint` has a lot of parameters that I don't know how to get.
Anyway I don't think that creating a new instance of `WebMonitorEndpoint` (or a subclass of it) is the correct approach because when the Application starts a new instance is created by Flink.

I hope can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/rest_api/#developing),

> A good example is the org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobExceptionsHandler that uses the org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.messages.JobExceptionsHeaders.

Regarding the #3 point, you should add the `CustomHandler` to the this [initializeHandler()](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/25697476095a5b9cf38dc3b61c684d0e912b1353/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/webmonitor/WebMonitorEndpoint.java#L279) function. Here is the example on `JobExceptionsHandler`

```
JobExceptionsHandler jobExceptionsHandler =
    new JobExceptionsHandler(
            leaderRetriever,
            timeout,
            responseHeaders,
            JobExceptionsHeaders.getInstance(),
            executionGraphCache,
            executor);
```

After initialization of the class, `add()` to the handler as described in the code,

```
handlers.add(Tuple2.of(jobExceptionsHandler.getMessageHeaders(), jobExceptionsHandler));
```

Comment: Hi, can you please show ho to add the `CustomHandler` to the `initializeHandler()`?
Can you attach a complete example, please?

Comment: Updated the answer