# Flink 1.18 register custom API endpoint handler

Tags: apache-flink

As per [this](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/ops/rest_api/#developing) I have created classes which implements

> To add new requests, one needs to
>
> - add a new MessageHeaders class which serves as an interface for the new request,
> - add a new AbstractRestHandler class which handles the request according to the added MessageHeaders class,
> - add the handler to org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorEndpoint#initializeHandlers().

but not sure how to do #3 of above, How can I add my own handler to which will support custom rest endpoint to serve the requests?

There question is similar to [Flink - Expose new custom REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75571722/5287108).

I have tried to find anything which will take my implpementation of AbstractRestHandler as parameter but found nothing within WebMonitorEndpoint